# Cannot POST data cross domain in Angular app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

**EDIT:**
Problem is resolved. My front end code is fine, it's error of back end guys.

I have problem when POST data cross domain. I don't know why, just 3 hours ago it worked fine. At that time I just made some changes in CSS and HTML, I was not touch to any JS file. I also asked the Back end team (They're using Ruby on Rails) and they told me that they still working on localhost.
This error appear every time I try to POST to server when using both Firefox and Chrome:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://time-traveler-back.herokuapp.com/api/sessions/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

For Chrome, I already installed CORS app. But if I turned it on, another error appear:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://time-traveler-back.herokuapp.com/api/sessions/login. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is my app config:

```
// Config for POST data cross domain
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
}]);
```

This is how I POST data:

```
var apiUrl = 'https://time-traveler-back.herokuapp.com/api/';
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: apiUrl + 'sessions/login',
    data: $.param(formData), // pass in data as strings
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
})
.then(function successCallback(response) {
    // my stuffs
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    // my stuffs
});
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Credentials and CORS
>
> One thing to note when using withCredentials: true in your app and
>   configuring the server for CORS is that you may not have your
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set to '*'. It must be configured
>   to a few select origins. If you absolutely must have this set to *,
>   then I suggest doing something beyond cookie based authentication,
>   such as token-based authentication.

See [AngularJS Authentication and CORS](https://gist.github.com/mlynch/be92735ce4c547bd45f6)

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, I still didn't get your idea.

Comment: Which part didn't you understand? Either you define your server to return a list of allowed clients instead of `*` (all) or you use another authentication process.

Comment: Thank you, but I edited my questions. It's back end team's mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a standard CORS error.

You already fixed, but in case of doubt, I'll give some recommendations:

---

[**`Rack-CORS`**](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

If using rails as the backend, you should definitely check out the `rack-cors` gem. This basically sets up all the CORS policies for your server through the middleware in the most simple way possible:

```
#config/application.rb
   ...
   config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
```

This allows you to permit particular domains "origins" & methods to your app.

--

You must also remember that to prevent cross domain XML requests, "CORS" (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) was instituted to apply a "lock" on which resources / urls are accessible by JS requests.

As a rule of thumb, if you're ever using JS to automagically update the front-end with an XML request of a ***separate domain*** (not just Ajax), you'll need to permit the domain in your server's CORS policy.

There are a number of ways to do this; simplest with rails is to use the `rack-CORS` gem (as above).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will come back here if I got that error in the future.